# STM32 + SD card (FATFS and SPI) + physical connection + FR_NOT_READY

Tags: stm32, sd-card, spi, fatfs

I am new to the world of stm and STM32CubeMX. So far, I was able to successfully implement SPI and I2C on a temperature sensor. Now I try to write data to an SD card, unfortunately so far without success. As a microcontroller I use the STM32L073RZT6 and the SD card module from Waveshare, which has an SDIO and SPI interface. My problem is that I have not yet seen any reasonable documentation that tells me how to properly connect the SD card to a microcontroller. In my previous attempt, I connected the microcontroller to the SD card module as follows:

- 3v3 <---> 3v3 (Pin1)
- GND <---> GND (Pin 2)
- PB3 (SCK) <---> SCLK (pin 5)
- PB4 (MISO) <---> MISO (DO) (Pin 3)
- PB5 (MOSI) <---> MOSI (DI) (pin 4)
- PA9 (GPIO OUT) <---> CS (Pin6)

[Pin_configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1sEh.png)
[sd_card_back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAx2l.jpg)

[sd_card_front](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njevl.jpg)
[mircrocontroller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18nDl.jpg)

[Pin_description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BpY2.jpg)

Did I properly connect the SD card to the microcontroller? What are CMD and CD? What do D0 to D3 serve? How would SDIO look like the configuration and physical connections from the microcontroller to the SD card?
At first I tried it with HAL_SPI_Transmit () and finally with the code below as described at https://blog.domski.pl/using-fatfs-with-hal/. The function f_open () returns the value FR_NOT_READY.

```
/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file           : main.c
  * @brief          : Main program body
  ******************************************************************************
  * This notice applies to any and all portions of this file
  * that are not between comment pairs USER CODE BEGIN and
  * USER CODE END. Other portions of this file, whether 
  * inserted by the user or by software development tools
  * are owned by their respective copyright owners.
  *
  * Copyright (c) 2019 STMicroelectronics International N.V. 
  * All rights reserved.
  *
  * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without 
  * modification, are permitted, provided that the following conditions are met:
  *
  * 1. Redistribution of source code must retain the above copyright notice, 
  *    this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
  * 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
  *    this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
  *    and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
  * 3. Neither the name of STMicroelectronics nor the names of other 
  *    contributors to this software may be used to endorse or promote products 
  *    derived from this software without specific written permission.
  * 4. This software, including modifications and/or derivative works of this 
  *    software, must execute solely and exclusively on microcontroller or
  *    microprocessor devices manufactured by or for STMicroelectronics.
  * 5. Redistribution and use of this software other than as permitted under 
  *    this license is void and will automatically terminate your rights under 
  *    this license. 
  *
  * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY STMICROELECTRONICS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS IS" 
  * AND ANY EXPRESS, IMPLIED OR STATUTORY WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT 
  * LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, FITNESS FOR A 
  * PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NON-INFRINGEMENT OF THIRD PARTY INTELLECTUAL PROPERTY
  * RIGHTS ARE DISCLAIMED TO THE FULLEST EXTENT PERMITTED BY LAW. IN NO EVENT 
  * SHALL STMICROELECTRONICS OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT,
  * INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT
  * LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, 
  * OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF 
  * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING 
  * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS SOFTWARE,
  * EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"
#include "stm32l0xx_hal.h"
#include "fatfs.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */

/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;

UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
FATFS fs;
FATFS *pfs;
FIL fil;
FRESULT fres;
DWORD fre_clust;
uint32_t total, free;
char buffer[100];

/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

/* USER CODE END 0 */

/**
  * @brief  The application entry point.
  *
  * @retval None
  */
int main(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration----------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_SPI1_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_FATFS_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */

    //https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/Micro_SD_Storage_Board
    HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_9,GPIO_PIN_SET); //set CS on high
    HAL_Delay(1000);

    //http://elm-chan.org/fsw/ff/00index_e.html

    /* Mount SD Card */
  if(f_mount(&fs, "", 0) == FR_OK) {
        //HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5);
  }
  /* Open file to write */
  if(f_open(&fil, "first.txt", FA_OPEN_ALWAYS | FA_READ | FA_WRITE) == FR_NOT_READY) {
        HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5);
  }

  /* Check free space */
  //if(f_getfree("", &fre_clust, &pfs) != FR_OK) HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5);

  //total = (uint32_t)((pfs->n_fatent - 2) * pfs->csize * 0.5);
  //free = (uint32_t)(fre_clust * pfs->csize * 0.5);   

  /* Free space is less than 1kb */
  //if(free < 1) HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5); 

  /* Writing text */
 // f_puts("STM32 SD Card I/O Example via SPI\n", &fil);  
  //f_puts("Save the world!!!", &fil);

  /* Close file */
  //if(f_close(&fil) != FR_OK) HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5); 

  /* Open file to read */
 // if(f_open(&fil, "first.txt", FA_READ) != FR_OK) HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5);

  //while(f_gets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), &fil))
  //{
    //printf("%s", buffer);
  //}

  /* Close file */
  //if(f_close(&fil) != FR_OK) HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5);    

  /* Unmount SDCARD */
  //if(f_mount(NULL, "", 1) != FR_OK) HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(GPIOA,GPIO_PIN_5);


  /* USER CODE END 2 */

  /* Infinite loop */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN WHILE */
  while (1)
  {

  /* USER CODE END WHILE */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

  }
  /* USER CODE END 3 */

}

/**
  * @brief System Clock Configuration
  * @retval None
  */
void SystemClock_Config(void)
{

  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct;
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct;
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit;

    /**Configure the main internal regulator output voltage 
    */
  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_MSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIState = RCC_MSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSICalibrationValue = 0;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.MSIClockRange = RCC_MSIRANGE_5;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_NONE;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Initializes the CPU, AHB and APB busses clocks 
    */
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_MSI;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART2;
  PeriphClkInit.Usart2ClockSelection = RCC_USART2CLKSOURCE_PCLK1;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

    /**Configure the Systick interrupt time 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000);

    /**Configure the Systick 
    */
  HAL_SYSTICK_CLKSourceConfig(SYSTICK_CLKSOURCE_HCLK);

  /* SysTick_IRQn interrupt configuration */
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, 0, 0);
}

/* SPI1 init function */
static void MX_SPI1_Init(void)
{

  /* SPI1 parameter configuration*/
  hspi1.Instance = SPI1;
  hspi1.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi1.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi1.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_HIGH;
  hspi1.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi1.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi1.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_32;
  hspi1.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi1.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi1.Init.CRCPolynomial = 7;
  if (HAL_SPI_Init(&hspi1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/* USART2 init function */
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    _Error_Handler(__FILE__, __LINE__);
  }

}

/** Configure pins as 
        * Analog 
        * Input 
        * Output
        * EVENT_OUT
        * EXTI
*/
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{

  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;

  /* GPIO Ports Clock Enable */
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
  __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

  /*Configure GPIO pin Output Level */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_9, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  /*Configure GPIO pins : PA5 PA9 */
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5|GPIO_PIN_9;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */

/* USER CODE END 4 */

/**
  * @brief  This function is executed in case of error occurrence.
  * @param  file: The file name as string.
  * @param  line: The line in file as a number.
  * @retval None
  */
void _Error_Handler(char *file, int line)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN Error_Handler_Debug */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the HAL error return state */
  while(1)
  {

  }
  /* USER CODE END Error_Handler_Debug */
}

#ifdef  USE_FULL_ASSERT
/**
  * @brief  Reports the name of the source file and the source line number
  *         where the assert_param error has occurred.
  * @param  file: pointer to the source file name
  * @param  line: assert_param error line source number
  * @retval None
  */
void assert_failed(uint8_t* file, uint32_t line)
{ 
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 6 */
  /* User can add his own implementation to report the file name and line number,
     tex: printf("Wrong parameters value: file %s on line %d\r\n", file, line) */
  /* USER CODE END 6 */
}
#endif /* USE_FULL_ASSERT */

/**
  * @}
  */

/**
  * @}
  */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

I am aware that there are examples of projects for the stm32 series, which could not help me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to use SDIO for the SD card but I have used SPI several times. Try this: https://www.controllerstech.com/sd-card-using-spi-in-stm32/. I have used it in my projects and it works.

The connections you said are correct:

> - 3v3 <---> 3v3 (Pin1)
> - GND <---> GND (Pin 2)
> - PB3 (SCK) <---> SCLK (pin 5)
> - PB4 (MISO) <---> MISO (DO) (Pin 3)
> - PB5 (MOSI) <---> MOSI (DI) (pin 4)
> - PA9 (GPIO OUT) <---> CS (Pin6)

The pin CD is for detect if the card is inserted or not. You can connect a pull-up resistor to it and while the card is not inserted that pin will be a high level and when the SD card is inserted it will be low level. You can use an interrupt for detect the insertion of the SD card and initialize it, for example, or make the code write data into the SD card only when it is inserted.

Comment: Are you able to read/write file with large file size? 

I have made FatFs library work on my STM32 F411 PCB board.


Basically I need to store 1000+ floating point values in SD card and read them back.
I have no problem in writing; but I cannot read all the records back.
I put each value in one line, ending with “\n” and use f_gets to read line by line.
After reading 900+ line, I have Assertion failed error.


Do you have any idea what goes wrong?

Comment: That reading error has sth to do with sector size. If I increase (double) the sector size when doing SD card formatting, I can read more lines before hitting that error.